# what's wrong with ARP Table in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, internet, arp

I use Windows 7. And I set entry of Gateway in ARP table is Static. 
But I set Mac's Gateway wrong and I can't use Internet. So I use command "arp -d" to delete ARP table, then I can use Internet.
But if i restart my PC, I can't use Internet until use "arp -d" again.

Why that? and how can i fix this bug?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers,  We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of **source code** in them.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: You created a permanent entry in the ARP table but your deletion is only temporary until next reboot. Replace the faulty entry with arp -s and the correct details.